# Laravel 5.3 Redirect to previous page after login success

Tags: redirect, authentication, laravel-5.3

i have /privatepage that only authenticated user able to access

questions:

1. how to redirect to /login, if i'm guest (not authenticated) and i hit /privatepage
2. once i'm successfully login from /login, how to redirect to the previous page (/privatepage)
3. similiar like no.2 - in /login page, if i come from /aboutpage (which a public page) - after login successfull, how do i redirect back to /aboutpage (or the previous page)?

Thank you,

AnD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use redirect()->intended()

Find more about it here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication

Comment: Thank you for the reply, may I asked where should i put this intended code?

Comment: When authentication you can use it like,  public function authenticate()
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }
    }`